# How to rollback the datacontext to the point of the last submitchanges

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I am working on an app that is inserting a lot of new objects (rows) and relationships between them. But at a certain point when an error occurs I want all the changes to the DataContext be disgarded and "thrown away". So that after an error I have a clean copy of the DataContext that matches the state of the database.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Alternatively, you could make use of the DataContext.Transaction, and use that to `.Commit()` or `.Rollback()` your changes.

**ORIG**

Just throw away that DataContext & Re-instantiate it.

Something like...

```
public void MyMethod(string connStr)
{
    try
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(connStr);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //Do Stuff
                //Insert Objects
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //So if it bombs in the loop, log your exception
            {
                Log(ex);
            }
            finally //Reinstantiate your DC
            {
                dc = new DataClasses1DataContext(connStr);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception bigEx)
    {
        Log(bigEx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the TransactionScope in a using statement. If you don't call .Complete() on the TransactionScope, all changes are rolled back when it is disposed (which happens when leaving the using statement).